# Symfony and xDebug View Variables

Tags: php, symfony1, xdebug

This will probably be a quick answer for somebody, but I haven't been able to find the answer.

I'm using xDebug with a Symfony application, and I find it quite annoying that xDebug cannot report my view variables to my variable view in eclipse.

I figured the solution would be to declare these variables as public in the scope of the component (/action), however when I declare my view variables there, they are no longer available in my Symfony view/partial.

Has anybody run into this same annoyance and found a solution?

**Edit**

I did some further investigation and found that *sfComponent* implements a __set() so that my variables are not actually (direct) properties of the object. This makes a lot of sense, but I would still like to be able to debug my view variables. If anybody has a solution, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: You're saying the variables are indirect properties of the object. I think they are stored in a parameter holder, aren't they? Why not inspect this parameter holder?

Comment: @greg0ire Debugging the parameter holder seems to work just fine. If you care to post this as an answer, I'll accept it as the "correct answer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

view variables are stored in a parameter holder, so they are still accessible from the view object. All you have to do is inspect the parameter holder variable.